# Find the value of BC

Tags: euclidean-geometry

If $DE+EF=10$ and $(AC)(EF)=40$, find BC.
[image]

I called $DE=x$, so $EF=10-x$, and we can find that $BD=\frac{20(5-x)}{x}$, but I couldn't do anymore in this question. I tried to find similar or equivalents triangles, but I didn't find.

Can someone give me a hint?
Thanks for atention.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no extra information? Is $EF$ tangent to the circle? Is $AF$ a diameter? Are $AF$ and $BE$ parallel (it does not look likely, but anyway)?

Comment: There is no more information in the original question, Dr. Mathva, just what I said :/

Comment: @Cavalo, is $FE$ tangent to the circle?

Comment: Yes, Doubnot! This isn't in the question, but the figure suggests this.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Line $FE$ is tangent to the circle as suggested in the original drawing. And the solution is not that hard.

We know the following:

$$EF=x,\ \ DE=10-x,\ \ AC=\frac{40}x\tag{1}$$

It's a well known (and easily provable) fact that:

$$EF'^2=EF^2=ED\cdot EB$$

It follows that:

$$EB=\frac{x^2}{10-x}$$

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{EB}{EF}=\frac{x}{10-x}\tag{2}$$

It's also a known fact that the angle $\alpha$ between tangent $FE$ and chord $FB$ is equal to the inscribed angle $\angle FAB$. So we know that:

$$\angle CAB=\alpha, \ \ \angle ABC=135^\circ-\alpha\tag{3}$$

Now apply law of sines to triangle $ABC$:

$$\frac{BC}{\sin\angle CAB}=\frac{AC}{\sin\angle ABC}$$

$$BC=AC\frac{\sin\angle ABC}{\sin\angle CAB}\tag{4}$$

Now replace (1) and (3) into (4):

$$BC=\frac{40}x\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin(135^\circ-\alpha)}=\frac{40}x\frac{\sin\alpha}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos\alpha+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin\alpha}$$

$$BC=\frac{40\sqrt2}{x}\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha}=\frac{40\sqrt2}{x}\frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\alpha+1}\tag{5}$$

Final touch: replace {2} into {5}:

$$BC=\frac{40\sqrt2}{x}\frac{\frac{x}{10-x}}{\frac{x}{10-x}+1}=4\sqrt{2}$$

Nice problem, deserved more attention.

Comment: Nice answer, too.